# Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'

Tags: typescript, express-session

I am using express-session in my project, but after update express-session to 1.17.1, tsc compilation getting some errors:

[image]

After add type merging like this:

[image]

The errors in the vscode editor are no longer existed. But when I run the tsc command, it still getting same errors:

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but in case anyone sees this, one way to work around this is using a typing stub. I wish I could reference the article I found when I ran into the same exact issue but I'll just regurgitate what it said..

I created a folder in root called 'typing-stubs' then sub folders for each type you're planning on extending with a file called index.d.ts

so in this example `typing-stubs\express-session\index.d.ts`

from there you can place your code

```
import session from 'express-session';

declare module 'express-session' {
  export interface SessionData {
    user: { [key: string]: any };
    userId: number;
  }
}
```

Then just make sure you reference this folder in your tsconfig file under "typeRoots"

```
  "typeRoots": [
    "./typing-stubs",
    "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I notice they provide an example of how to declaration merge which you've implemented, it would be worth providing a codesandbox.
I'm imagining your ts compiler is missing your declaration file, include this in the `tsconfig.json` under the files section, otherwise it'd be worth providing a code sandbox and I'll look :)

If I'm not mistaken, the type for SessionData appears to be under a namespace of session (line 213) `https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express-session` so you'll want to export the interface from under that namespace (notice how the declare line changes, and also exporting the interface)

```
declare namespace session {
  export interface SessionData {
    userId: any;
    loadedCount: number;
  }
}
```